# How do I enter an @ at the beginning of cell (when its not a formula)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I often need to do such things as enter a column of twitter handles. But if I start a cell by typing "@", excel assumes its a formula, and worse, refuses to accept a bad formula.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

usually you can use `'` at the beginning of a cell to show the value as a string.

Comment: Wow, this is an awesome trick. The column/cell does not even need to be formatted as text first for this to work.

Comment: Yeah, it's a handy one, especially if you want to start with an `=`

Comment: @DragonFax -- you should accept this as the answer. The tick mark at the beginning of a cell is the universally accepted way to do this.

Comment: would have been accepted faster but stackexchange seems to have stopped emailing me. will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Through experimentation, I found that I can set the whole column with a format of "Text" and that convinces Excel to accept the poorly formated "formulas". So this is a workable solution.

But I don't accept this as an elegant or proper solution, as it still assumes the input is a formula, and it acts as so (trying to sum other cells clicked, and such) until I force it to finish editing the cell. In other words, I don't trust the results of this solution.